# SQL ORACLE APEX Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have a query in ORACLE APEX that is appearing with an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R4bi.jpg)

How would this be resolved?

Comment: Please avoid images, post the text instead

Comment: What should the part ORDER BY COUNT(*) do? This seems to be incorrect. The order by clause ususally is used with column names.

Comment: you have an extra parenthesis at the end

Comment: Oracle does not support the `LIMIT` keyword.